# Why TYPO3 Realurl works but page not found

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, typo3, realurl

We installed realurl 2.2.0 in TYPO3 8.7 LTS. The default TYPO3 .htaccess file is copied to the index folder and we use the following settings (domain replaced):

vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName    example.com
    DocumentRoot  /var/www/examplecom/htdocs
    <Directory /var/www/examplecom/htdocs/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Typoscript:

```
config.tx_realurl_enable = 1
config.simulateStaticDocuments = 0
config.baseURL = http://example.com/
```

Realurl is set to automatic.
Server runs with php 7.0 and Apache 2.

The links in the generated HMENU works properly. But when I click on one of the navigation elements a 404 page not found message appears. Why is that? How to fix?

Comment: Is the apache module mod_rewrite active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to enable apache module rewrite:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```